# Trouble with running updates

Tags: release-hera, updates

I'm running my usual sudo apt upgrade and I'm getting the following and not sure what it means or what I need to do:

````
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                    
Hit:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                                                            
Hit:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                                                                          
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/flexiondotorg/audio/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                    
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                               
Hit:7 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                               
Hit:8 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic InRelease                                                                                                
Hit:9 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com bionic InRelease                                                                                         
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/philip.scott/elementary-tweaks/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                        
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                               
Hit:12 https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable InRelease                            
Hit:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                                        
Err:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wireguard/wireguard/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                               
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Hit:15 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                       
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/wireguard/wireguard/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/wireguard/wireguard/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/i18n/Translation-en_GB' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/dep11/icons-128x128.tar' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/i18n/Translation-en_GB' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-128x128.tar' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_GB' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/icons-128x128.tar' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?```
````

Thanks

How do I get rid of the long list of 'Skipping acquire of configured file'? I don't know what it means

Comment: Does https://askubuntu.com/questions/1282254/apt-update-gives-error-for-wireguard help?

Comment: It doesn't. If i try the remove command I get 

```sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:wireguard/wireguard
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~wireguard/ubuntu/wireguard'.
The team named '~wireguard' has no PPA named 'ubuntu/wireguard'
Please choose from the following available PPAs:```

Comment: If i add the universe bit I get 
```sudo apt-add-repository universe
'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.```

Comment: I've just googled Wiregaurd because I've never heard of it and it's some sort of VPN. I use Nordvpn - is it part of that? Or is it something that is part of Elementary? If I don't need it because I use Nordvpn then can I get rid of this Wireguard? Why would I even have it?

Comment: I guess you're just gonna have to edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and delete all lines containing the wireguard ppa. Yes, wireguard is a VPN provider, and I cannot tell you how you got it installed, but the point is that ppa is throwing errors cause it is no longer active. Even if you might need the wireguard package in the future, it is inlcuded in the ubuntu repositories now. Also look inside the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` folder, and delete any files with wireguard in their names, if any.

Comment: Thanks. I unticked the line for Wireguard using an app called Software and Updates - it was in the list on the 'Other Software' tab. Is Software and Updates part of Elementary??

Comment: See https://ubuntu.forumming.com/question/5471/how-to-resolve-skipping-acquire-of-configured-file-ubuntu-18-04-2-lts for the other warnings. I am really curious as to how did your source.list file get populated with such missformed ppas :D

Comment: Hi Vlad - just found your answer above - it was hidden until I clicked on '2 more comments'. Your link for solving the other warnings doesn't help me - I don't understand what I'm meant to do from that link you gave me. It looks like I have to delete a line or replace a line. I don't know how to find such a line to start with

Comment: So,the link above details a simple solution, that might work for you: go to the same `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, find the lines containing `archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` and put a `#` in front of them (comment them out); save the file and run a `sudo apt update`. After that,, uncomment the lines and run `sudo apt update` again.

Comment: I've figured out how to see what is in that file using something called Code. However, it says I cannot save changes to this file and will need to save changes elsewhere

Comment: Right click Files -> New Window  as Administrator, type your password. Noe you'll be able to save the changes made to that file.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by 'Right click Files'. I haven't got a Files to right click. What exactly are you referring to?

Comment: Also, what are multiverse, universe and restricted?

Comment: I do struggle with Linux stuff. Every time I google something I don't quite understand I find an explanation that usually has another thing I need to google within the first line or so. I do try my best but sometimes end up so far away that it's hard to keep track of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: So, my muddled understanding so far is that the sources.list file tells the apt command where to go to look for stuff when doing the apt update. Anything with a # at the start of a line is a 'comment' and is not actually used by the apt command. My error messages imply there is a problem finding things in bionic InRelease. What is bionic InRelease?

Comment: Also, (sorry about this - so many confusing things and so many questions) the top of the sources.list file mentions 5.0 Juno but About in Settings says I'm on 5.1.7 Hera

Comment: So, rather than use Code which won't let me save changes to the sources.list file then I'm going to try use something called vi or vim which I think allows me to edit files in the terminal rather than in an app

Comment: Right. I managed to get my head around using vim, or rather sudo vim as just using vim it was read only. And this has solved the problem. As usual, I've no idea why it worked. Googling and asking for solutions to problems does usually do the trick, and the help is always appreciated. I just wish I understood things a bit more

Comment: By 'right click Files' I meant click on Applications -> right click Files app -> New Window as Administrator' . Now you'll be able to edit and delete files like a sane person :D

Comment: Right. I seem to have two Files applications in Applications - one with a folder with a house on it icon and one with a blue filing cabinet icon (I usually use this one). Right clicking the folder with the house on it icon gives me the 'New Window as Administrator'. So I browse to sources.list then I can right click and open with Code, Vim or GVim. Brill, thanks. Just off too google what GVim might be

Answer (score 0):

Now when I run sudo apt update I get:

```
Hit:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                                                                             
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                  
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                   
Hit:5 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                                                            
Hit:6 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com bionic InRelease                                                                                         
Hit:7 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                                                                          
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/flexiondotorg/audio/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                 
Hit:9 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                      
Hit:10 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic InRelease                                                           
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                          
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/philip.scott/elementary-tweaks/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:14 https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                      
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
3 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/i18n/Translation-en_GB' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/dep11/icons-128x128.tar' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/i18n/Translation-en_GB' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-128x128.tar' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_GB' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/icons-128x128.tar' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

Comment: The IP error for Wireguard has gone but I still get this long list of 'Skipping acquire of configured file' so once again I don't know what this is or what I need to do.

Comment: You should have added this information to your question, not as an answer. You can always edit your question sto include new information.

Comment: That list of stuff is in my question. I was pointing out that it is still not sorted so far. I've edited my question now as requested